# What output exactly is captured by -Streaminghost in Start-ThreadJob?

Tags: multithreading, powershell

When running code as a `ThreadJob` in PowerShell 7.2.11 (also applies to 7.2.13), I've noticed that not all output is affected by the `-Streaminghost` argument.

```
Start-ThreadJob {
  Write-Host 'Hello'
} -Streaminghost $Host
```

will output `Hello`,

but using `Write-Output` in the thread will not show the output until I do a `Get-Job | Receive-Job`...

```
Start-ThreadJob {
  Write-Output 'Hello'
} -Streaminghost $Host
```

```
Start-ThreadJob {
  'Hello'
} -Streaminghost $Host
```

What gives?

Comment: `-StreamingHost $Host` means that all streams except stdout and stderr are hooked directly to the `PSHost`. In other words, all runspaces spawned are hooked using the [`PSHost` overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runspaces.runspacefactory.createrunspace?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0#overloads)

Comment: Ok, but I kind of need stdout :) Is there a way to redirect that stream?

Comment: Why would you want to hook stdout to `$Host` ? Assuming you could, how that would be useful ? When a stream is hooked to `$Host` you simply cannot capture it. If you want streaming parallel output then install pwsh 7+ and use `ForEach-Object -Parallel`

Comment: I am using PWSH 7 :) For some occasions, I'd liked all output of my code to be displayed on the console regardless of it is running in a background thread or not.

Comment: I see but that would require to either block the thread while streaming output (like how `ForEach-Object -Parallel` does) or write directly to the host which is also possible but then you cannot capture that output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) has provided the crucial pointers:

- The purpose of [`Start-ThreadJob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob)'s `-StreamingHost` parameter is to directly connect all [output streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams) *other* than the *success* and the *error* output streams to the specified PowerShell host.

  - If you pass the [automatic `$Host` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#host), i.e. the host of the *current session*, whatever is output to those streams then surfaces:

    - *instantly, asynchronously*, i.e. it may be randomly interspersed with the synchronous output produced later in the same script / an interactive session.
    - without any ability to *capture* these outputs.
- The success and the error stream outputs - as the outputs from *all* streams are *by default* - are quietly collected by the resulting job and require [`Receive-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/receive-job) to be retrieved *on demand* later.

---

If you truly want to surface *all* output streams from the thread job *instantly, asynchronously*, you can use the following technique, which uses [redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection) `*>&1`, which merges all outputs streams into the success output stream, and pipes the result to [`Out-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/out-host) for direct-to-host output:

```bash
$job = Start-ThreadJob {
  & {
    Write-Host 'Hello host'
    Write-Output 'Hello success'
    Write-Error 'Hello error'
  } *>&1 | Out-Host
} -StreamingHost $Host
```

Note: The above also outputs a (non-terminating) *error* in addition to host (`Write-Host`) and success output (`Write-Output`) to demonstrate that all output surfaces instantly, asynchronously.

Comment: Thx for your excellent help. But it's time for me to revisit this subject. What about `throw 'Error thrown'`? I can't seem to be able to redirect that kind of errors. I could of course use `try - catch` statements.

Comment: @Dennis, `throw` creates a _runspace-terminating_ error ("script-terminating error") that terminates execution of the script block. Unless you catch it with `try` / `catch` inside the script block, you'll only be able to surface it via a `Receive-Job` call later.

Comment: Right. What about output from `Set-PsDebug -Trace 2`? I can redirect it using StreamingHost but I can't seem to use Receive-Job to get the trace of a job.

Comment: @Dennis, unfortunately, it looks like trace output is outside the system of PowerShell streams, so it isn't captured as part of a job's output. Another example is `-WhatIf` output. If you feel strongly about this, you can open a feature request at https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues.